# Multiple worker to same queue messages

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have a task to migrate keys (S3 objects) from one S3 account to another S3 account as soon as possible. I would like to publish keys in a single queue but want multiple workers(Running on different EC2 instances) to consume keys from the same queue in parallel manner.

[image: Flow diagram]

Let's say I am publishing 1000 keys continuously in the queue and there are 5 workers consuming keys from queue. I want each 1000 to be picked by each different worker and all process keys parallely.

I am not sure how to do it and distinguish which worker has already picked keys and which one yet to pick.

Comment: Do you wish to process the messages using an AWS Lambda function, or 'workers' that run somewhere (eg on Amazon EC2 instances or your own computers)?

Comment: These workers are running on different EC2 instances @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 2):

You should create:

- An **Amazon SQS queue**
- An **AWS Lambda function** that is configured to Trigger when a message is sent to the SQS queue, and which will process the keys mentioned in the message(s)
- Something that will 'push' the keys as messages into the SQS queue

The Amazon SQS queue will automatically trigger the AWS Lambda function when a message is available. It can pass up to 10 messages to each Lambda function being invoked and the default is a maximum of 1000 concurrently-running Lambda functions.

Each 'message' could contain a single key or multiple keys -- that is up to you to decide. The Lambda function simply needs to know how to process the message that you have sent.

The Lambda function will receive the message(s) in the `event['Records']` list (array). It should process those messages and then exit the function. This will cause those messages to be deleted from the queue. If the function does not exit successfully (eg if there is an error generated), the messages will automatically reappear on the queue for re-processing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the workers on Amazon EC2 instances, then each worker should do the following:

- Loop forever, doing these steps:

  - Call `receiveMessage()` with `WaitTimeSeconds = 20` -- this will wait up to 20 seconds before returning an empty response, which reduces the number of times the worker will call the queue
  - Loop through `Messages` array that is returned
  - For each message in the array, process the message and then call `deleteMessage()`, passing the `ReceiptHandle` of the message

Each worker can request up to 10 messages per `ReceiveMessage()` call.

It is up to you what to put in the message -- it might be a single key or it might be multiple keys. You should code your worker to know how to interpret the message.

So, if you require that each worker gets 1000 keys, the you should send 1000 keys in a single message and configure each worker to use `MaxNumberOfMessages = 1` when calling `receiveMessage()`. However, I would recommend that you use smaller quantities to more-evenly distribute the work amongst the workers.